# How to scrape the pitcher's name and team?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, python-requests, findall

I am new to scraping/coding and could use some help if possible.

```
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  import requests
  import pandas as pd

  page_link ='https://www.baseball-reference.com/previews/index.shtml'
  page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=5)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")
```

I need help finding the appropriate way to find to extract the pitcher's name and team.

(examples only:)

```
  player_name = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('td', {'href': 'example-name'})]

  team = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('td', {'href': 'example-team'})]
```

Here is where I export to excel:

```
  my_dict = dict(zip(player_name, team))

  df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(my_dict))

  writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pitching_webscrape.xlsx')
  df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
  writer.save()
```

I would like the pitcher's name and team imported to excel. Thanks in advance for your help! Please let me know if I can improve my question or add more details.

Here is the code I had so far:

```
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  import requests
  import pandas as pd
  page_link ='https://www.baseball-reference.com/previews/index.shtml'
  page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=5)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")
```

My first code:

```
  t = soup.find_all('td')
  print(t)
```

My first output:

[[Blue Jays](/teams/TOR/2018.shtml) (60-70) , , 
[Preview](/previews/2018/BAL201808270.shtml)
, [Orioles](/teams/BAL/2018.shtml) (37-94) , , 7:05PM
            , **TOR**, [Sam Gaviglio](https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/g/gavigsa01.shtml)
(#43, 28, RHP, 3-6, 4.94), **BAL**, [David Hess](https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/h/hessda01.shtml)
(#41, 24, RHP, 2-8, 5.50), [White Sox](/teams/CHW/2018.shtml) (51-79) , ,

My second code:

```
  t = soup.find_all('td')
  for a in t:
      print(a.text)
```

My second output:

Blue Jays (60-70)

Preview

Orioles (37-94)

7:05PM

TOR
Sam Gaviglio(#43, 28, RHP, 3-6, 4.94)
BAL
David Hess(#41, 24, RHP, 2-8, 5.50)
White Sox (51-79)

I am getting closer,however, I only want the player's names and team's names. (i.e. TOR, Sam Gaviglio). I also want this imported into excel. Thanks! =)

Comment: I originally added 4 spaces to indent. I agree, though, so I added 2 more spaces. Does that look better @T.Woody?

Comment: Yes sir, but I didn't indent it because the code is not right. Do you think it would be better to indent that as well?

Comment: I believe I edited everything as requested. Please let me know if there are any other changes that are needed. Thanks for your help! =)

Comment: What has been your problem so far? Can you provide an example of outputs and expected results?

Comment: I added my output. It looks different once I copied and pasted it, though. I only want the pitcher's names and the teams they play for (i.e. Sam Gaviglio, TOR); (i.e. David Hess, BAL)

Comment: I will be back to look at this later, if no one has responded. Also, to let me know that you responded to me, use the `@T.Woody` feature of stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a single `list` of players and teams, then this should suffice:

```
import re
players_and_teams = []

for i in soup.find_all('td'):
    if i.find_all('a'):
        for link in i.find_all('a'):
            if not re.findall(r'Preview',link.text):
                players_and_teams.append(link.text)
```

Comment: This worked great for extracting just the info I wanted @gregory! I have two questions if you don't mind: 1) Is there anyway to remove the word "Preview" from the list? It is listed multiple times. 2) How do I save this printed list to a variable (i.e. player_name) so I can export this data to excel? I did an attempted example above under the section "examples only". Thank you sir for this knowledge... I am very thankful!

Comment: I've updated my answer to remove all the "Previews" with a regex filter. And, I've also shown how you could save all the players and teams to a list to use for exporting to excel.

Comment: Good morning @gregory... I just realized that all of my code looks pretty sloppy... I apologize for that. I am just learning and will do my best to improve. Do you recommend that I edit the code to look more clean? I am not sure if I am supposed to leave it as is or show the updated version. Thanks again sir! Enjoy your day!

Comment: @AbleArcher It is good practice to continue to edit your questions to clarify the issue you were having, but not correct them. The idea is someone else who's having your issue will come here to look at solutions to their problem.

Comment: Thanks @gregory for the info! I will do my best to make the necessary changes.